# Wifi Connection Problem

Tags: wi-fi

I am staying in hostel where i get WiFi facility.Using netcut application some are blocking the net connection.I can use internet in laptop using netcut defender but i am unable access  in my phone.I am using asus zenfone 5.
Is there any way to protect from blocking.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in Play Store. See if it works - [NetCut Root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.number5.netcut&hl=en).
Comment if worked.